# Macbook Pro - remote accessing inquiry

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, remote-access, osx-yosemite, privacy-protection

I just bought a used second-hand Macbook Pro, it is already functioning with OS and stuffs and a lot of apps.

Im already using it, I didn't have it reformatted or whatsoever, so the previous owners files are still here, together with all his apps etc.

My question is:

Is the previous owner have a way to access my personal files that I will be saving here, since he is the previous owner, Im not really sure if whether he puts any tracking software here whatsoever, that he will have the ability to monitor, see, get or read the personal files of the next owner?

Is there a thing as such?
Is it possible?

If the answer is YES, please let me know in details what to check, how to check, the location of folders, possible apps/softwares that needs to be removed.

I dont want to do a reformatting, Im already using it, no time for starting from scratch.

Thanks,

Elena

Comment: If you are worried.  Just reinstall the operating system and attach it to your own Apple account.  You don't indicate what version of OS X or which model you have.  What is and is not possible depends on several factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not going to be re formatting the drive then there can definitely be ways of accessing the computer.  At the top of my head

LogMeIn
TeamViewer
VNC
iCloud
ssh

I did a quick google search and came across this article.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58820/how-to-know-if-mac-os-x-machine-is-being-remotely-viewed

This may assist you in determining whats on your computer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's not that I dont want to do refomatting. The case is that I had already used the macbook pro for weeks, then a friend warned me. So my worries is that, do the previous owner already accessed my files or not? Thanks.

Comment: @ chindall - How can I know if my macbook pro had been accessed before and whether there were any files transferred from here to somewhere else?

Comment: @mewowlol You can use Apple's Console program to review the logs.

Comment: @ chindall - Where is that, how to open that Apple's Console program? Im just a newbie, just had my very first mac?

Comment: @ chindall - Found it. What are the keywords do I need to search to be able to find out if there are signs of my system and files being monitored from outside? Or if there are files transferred from here to somewhere else? Thanks.

Comment: @mewowlol I'd search for "connected" "logged in" "transferring" "remote".  That should give you a head start.

Comment: @ chindall - Thank you very much. One last question, so if I enable now Firewall and Block all incoming connections, I will be safe from now on, no need to worry if I turn it on and leave it that way?

Answer (score 0):

Previous owner could have used spyware to view the files on your system

If your computer is currently being monitored it may be dangerous to try to research spyware or use anti- spyware scanners. If your computer is compromised, spyware will log all of this research activity and alert the previous owner.

Spyware typically runs in stealth mode using disguised file names so it can be extraordinarily difficult to detect spyware programs that are already on your computer

You can use anti-spyware detection programs available in the web to find the culprit and you can tighten your security through firewall

Comment: @ vembutech - Where can I find a free good anti-spyware detection program? I just want to know if whether my files were already been accessed in the past weeks or not? Because if I find out that it is being accessed, I think its time for me to change all my online accounts passwords, facebook, twitters, bank accounts, etc etc. How can I know if there are files transferred from here to somewhere else, and if Im being monitored in the past 2 weeks?